# where is the default location for all databases in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to find the default location for all my local databases using sql server. Does anyone know?

Comment: What version?  It's version dependent..

Comment: sqlexpress, i think 2005

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Info here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143547%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

For you it should be `\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.90\MSSQL\Data\`

Answer (score 7):

try this `exec dbo.sp_helpdb <db_name>;`

if all you need is the files, use short one as `use <db_name> exec sys.sp_helpfile;`

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2005 / 2008 it should be somewhere like C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA.

Search C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server for .mdf files.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean the location of the .mdf and .ldf files? for sql server 2008 on my machine those default to:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA

Answer (score 1):

For `Microsoft SQL 2014`, try following location:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA`

Goodluck.